# Unable to convert List<object> to List<myClass> using Automapper and FileHelper restriction

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map my List to List which I'm unable to get.

**Scenario**: A flat file with fixed length records should be loaded into database.

**Constraint**: The layout of the flat file is defined in the database and I use "Filehelper" nuget to parse the records. Since the layout is configured in the database, I use `var fileHelperEngine = new FileHelperEngine(classBuilder.CreateRecordClass());` in order to generate the FixedFieldLength dynamically. When I create engine with the above code, the results returned is `List<object>` using the code `var parseResult = fileHelperEngine.ReadFileAsList(file);`

Ultimately, I need to convert the `List<object>` to `List<myClass>` before I call the SQLBulkCopy code.

When I didn't use the dynamic class builder, I used this code `var engine = new FixedFileEngine<T>()` to create the engine and it returns me `T[]` result which I can convert to `List<T>`, but when it returns o`bject[]` or `List<object>`, I'm unable to convert. I tries to use `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` and nothing seems to work.

Can anyone please tell me how do I convert `List<object>` to `List<myClass>`? I use **Automapper** as shown below, but it returns `null`. The column names in the object class is different from "myClass", I tried used "**ForMember**" method and it threw exception that column can't be found,

```
private List<T> MapParseRecordsFromObjectToT(List<object> parseRecords)
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                   {
                       cfg.CreateMap<object, T>()
                           // what should I do here??
                           ;
                   });
                var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                var source = new List<object>(parseRecords);

                return mapper.Map<List<object>, List<T>>(source);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the _actual_ type of the objects in `parseRecords`? Will there be different source types that correspond to different output types?

Comment: the parseRecords come from fileHelperEngine.ReadFileAsList(file) which is of type "List<object>". It actually contains data of destination type only, but the thing is, I can't convert from object to T

Comment: When you say "data of destination type" you mean some unknown type with the same properties?  or the objects are _actually_ the same type?

Comment: let me put this way. I have a flat file with MemberNameAgeDOB. Eg. John3501011980. A class is built with fields "Name", "Age" and "DOB". Now, the layout (fixed length) of these fields come from database which I'm doing using FixedLengthClassBuilder. When I use FileHelper to parse the flatfile, it returns me "List<object>" with Name, Age and DOB. (now this is source), but I wanted the data to be as List<Members>. So I try to use "AutoMapper" to convert which doesn't happen. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, because `object` does not have `Name` or `Age` properties, which means that the _actual_ type is something different. My question is, _do you know what that type is_, which it sounds like you don't.  Have you looked at [dynamic mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping)?

Comment: I tried dynamic mapping and gave this error.. Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping... hope this error will tell what the source and destination types are?

Mapping types:
List`1 -> myClass
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] -> myNameSpace.myClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126917/discussion-between-achutha-krishnan-and-d-stanley).